# Data structure required for arranging objects based on a rule

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

N students in a class play a game against each other, where each student plays against all other students in the class.

Also, the class leader has to arrange the students in a line, where each student lost the match with the student immediately in front of him.

> For example:
>
> Let there be 4 students A, B, C, and D
>
> Total number of matches: 6( (A,B), (A,C), (A,D), (B,C), (B,D), (C,D) )
>
> Match results:
>
> A def B
>
> C def A
>
> A def D
>
> C def B
>
> B def D
>
> C def D
>
> So the order is: C A B D

For storing the student objects, I am using the following data structure:

```
struct node {
    int student_id;
    int wins;
}
```

I am using a priority queue to arrange the students, with more priority given to those who have more wins.

If two or more objects have same priority then how do I arrange them?

I'm thinking of keeping a directed graph based on who wins against whom, and then doing a topological sort. Will it work?

Comment: Does the first sentence have anything to do with your question? The second seems unrelated and missing information. What input are you given?

Comment: Yes, here the students are the objects. Is it clear now?

Comment: No, it‘s not. What input are you given?

Comment: Sorry for the poor presentation, i will modify it to make it more clear

Comment: Also, I don't understand how this is not self-contradictory: "Also, if the class leader has to arrange the students in a line where each student would have lost the match with the student in front of him. student may or may not have won the match with the student front of front of him."

Comment: @MadPhysicist It is clear... See let 1 defeat 2 and 2 defeat three. And there is no information about 1 and 3 relationship. So this means they will in order 1 2 3.

Comment: You don't need an explicit directed graph. If every student plays every other student, the structure can be represented by half of an NxN matrix.

Comment: @VidorVistrom. Can you please update the question to reflect that? The sentences you have now do not mean that at all.

Comment: @VidorVistrom. It also says "each student plays against all other students in the class", meaning that you do have information about 1 and 3.

Comment: Please give me 5 minutes i will check the source and update the question

Comment: @MadPhysicist I have edited the question, now it has to be peer reviewed

Comment: I am not sure about what to do when the graph is cyclic, but if it is acyclic, best thing would be make a priority queue arrange from highest to lowest. Make a directed graph of same priority members, do its topological sort to determine its order. Is this a homework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First student will play against N-1 players
>
> Second student shall play against N-2 remaining players
>
> .
>
> .
>
> .
>
> N-1 shall play against 1 remaining player.
>
> Nth player has played against all by now.

Hence number of matches played:

> N-1+N-2....+1+0= N(N-1)/2

---

> I'm thinking of keeping a Directed graph based on who wins on whom,
>   and then do a topological sort, will it work?

It should work when the graph is Acyclic. Just make sure that direction is from A to B when A def. B. Else you will have to reverse the stack trace.

I am skeptical about cyclic scenario. But there is a simpler way:

Let there be 5 players: A B C D E

Sort the list on the basis of wins like this:

x def y(x->y)

A->B

A->D

B->C

B->D

B->E

C->A

D->C

D->E

E->A

E->C

Now start by first win listed above.

A->B
String: A B

A->D
Now D can come either before B or after B.
On look-up, B->D. Implies String: A B D

B->C
On look-up, D->C
String: A B D C

B->E
On look-up, E->C
This implies E has to come before C. 
On-look up D->E

String: A B D E C

String length is 5. STOP.

Comment: Not sure if your algorithm provides a general solution.

Comment: @MadPhysicist there can be multiple solutions to this problem. Even if you do a topological sort, multiple solutions exist. This should work because alphabetically you are starting from lowest and placing losers after. And this will give you one of the solutions

Comment: At the very least you should start by checking if there is a student that won all their games and if there is a student that lost all their games. There can only be one of each, and they must be placed at the beginning and end of the list, respectively, or the solution will not work.

Comment: @MadPhysicist It shall automatically place, since you are looking up both the current string and the win list(in Alphabetical order). I tried that too

Answer (score 1):

That data structure won't work. Whatever structure you chose must be able to store who the student beat/was beaten by. Something like this world work:

```
struct node{
    int student_id
    bool wins[n]
}
```

where wins[n] would represent a win against student ID==n
 from  there, it is path finding but in "normal" circumstances you could sum wins, sort by that and check that that is correct making changes if it is not

Comment: OK, but can you specify how to sort the list

Comment: in my structure i was keeping "wins" as the sum. And what if 2 student have same wins then how to sort. And if this case never arises i will need to prove the same.

Comment: to prove you have a correct answer is trivial: go down the list and check that each person lost to the person in front. for i = 1;i<n if(que[i].win[i-1]). note that you don't care who beat the person in front and you don't care who the last person beat, so cyclic wins is fine. when that easy solution doesn't work you can treat this as collections of nodes with one-way connections to other nodes. you need to use a path finding system looking for a path that trverses each node only once.